# How to implement try_files function similar to nginx on k8s gateway api ？

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-gateway-api

Our company fully uses the k8s gateway api as the unified entrance to the outside world for the cluster, but the front-end uses the history routing mode, which must be implemented through the try_files feature on nginx. Currently, the k8s gateway api does not have this feature, so many people are using the gateway api. How did you solve this problem?
The following are the relevant documents of k8s gateway api. No relevant configuration was found
https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/guides/

The following is my implementation, and I found that it cannot meet the needs.

- backendRefs:

  - group: ""
    kind: Service
    name: xizhao-web-saas-main
    port: 80
    weight: 1
    matches:
  - path:
    type: PathPrefix
    value: /
- matches:

  - path:
    type: PathPrefix
    value: /main/
  - path:
    type: PathPrefix
    value: /institution/
    filters:
  - type: RequestRedirect
    requestRedirect:
    path:
    type: ReplaceFullPath
    replaceFullPath: /
    statusCode: 302